# Update a record to its default values[MetaData]

Tags: apex, metadata-api, sobject

I want to refresh a record to the default values that we used while creating those fields ie in metadata. My object has around 100 fields, so manually searching and doing it is troublesome. I can use SObjectField from Schema.SObjectType.MyObject__C to iterate over all fields and initialize them. But I have to hardcode all the default values . I there a way in which i can set default value of field via apex

Comment: Hi....Can you explain your question in a bit more detail that what exactly you need to do ?

Comment: In theory you could use [DescribeFieldResult.getDefaultValue()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getDefaultValue) on each of the fields to get the default value from the metadata. But at present for some field types this is broken and won't be fixed for a while - see the known issue [DescribeFieldResult.getDefaultValue() returns null for Checkbox field and Picklist field](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XL8AAM).

Comment: Adding to what @KeithC suggested, you could just check the field type of the field and handle checkbox and picklist field separately.

Comment: I did exactly what Keith and Prakash suggested nd did my job for all editable field expect picklist nd checkbox. It helped.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it will work but you can try by creating a custom setting with two fields named "Field Name" & "Default Field Value". Then create the data for all fields and its default values in custom setting. Then retrieve the default value from here into the apex code and update your record.

Regards!
Ruchi

Comment: Creating extra field won't do job. In near future it will cross 300 fields nd exactly maintaing same field for duplicate values is troublesome nd will cross max field limits of Salesforce

Comment: @susanoochidori  :  I have not asked to create field in object. Rather I have asked to create a new custom setting and then only two fields  by the name of "Field Name" and "Default Value" . There data can be created then for the fields default values of the object.